# Regular expression in java Alphanumeric !@#$+.:=&*_-

Tags: java, regex

I need a Regular expression in java while allows following `Alphanumeric !@#$+.:=&*_-` value

This is what I have tried `[A-Z0-9!@#$+.:=&*_-]+`

This is how I am using it

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9!@#$+.:=&*_-]+");
p.matcher("value").matches();
```

Comment: what's wrong with the above? `[A-Za-z0-9!@#$+.:=&*_-]+`

Comment: It accepts other character like "[] etc

Comment: How are you using this regex? Your regex works fine for me (except not matching lower case characters since there is no `a-z` in your regex)

Comment: "It accepts other character like "[] etc" no it doesn't.

Comment: "It accepts other character like "[] etc" no it doesn't." let me retry

Comment: Please show us the exact code that you say accepts other characters. Not an example code but your real code and the real string that you are feeding it and the real `if` or `while` it does based on the match.

Comment: @anubhava He doesn't have to if he uses the `matches()` method.

Comment: You should also add `a-z` in small case though it might not solve the problem but its better

Comment: @Pshemo  can you please make it an answer so that i can accept it ?

Comment: Did u just forgot lower case ?

Comment: "[]{}().,; this string is being accepted" then you are not showing us code you are using since code you posted doesn't accept this string: http://ideone.com/q1cTgd

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot the lower case characters. Try `"[A-Za-z0-9!@#$+.:=&*_-]+"`

Answer (score 0):

String pattern = "([A-Za-z0-9!@#$+.:=&*_-]*)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

you can refer here to know basics

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/index.html

Answer (score -1):

'.' is a special character in regex. It matches all characters, hence your pattern is accepting [ and ]. You need to escape the '.' using '\' for it to match only the '.' character. Modify your pattern as `[A-Za-z0-9!@#$+\.:=&*_-]+` and try.

Comment: `.` is special, but only outside of `[...]`.